# How can I validate a Solana wallet address with web3js?

Tags: typescript, web3js, solana

I'm trying to validate that the input text I get from a user is a valid Solana address.

According to the web3.js documentation, the method .isOnCurve() does that:

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#isOnCurve

I've managed to make it work with this code:

```
import {PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js'

function validateSolAddress(address:string){
    try {
        let pubkey = new PublicKey(address)
        let  isSolana =  PublicKey.isOnCurve(pubkey.toBuffer())
        return isSolana
    } catch (error) {
        return false
    }
} 

function modalSubmit(modal: any){

  const firstResponse = modal.getTextInputValue(walletQuestFields.modal.componentsList[0].id)
 
  let isSolAddress = validateSolAddress(firstResponse)

  if (isSolAddress) {
    console.log('The address is valid')
  }else{
    console.log('The address is NOT valid')
  }
}
```

But when I pass  `let pubkey = new PublicKey(address)` a string that is not similar to a solana address, it throws the exception `Error: Invalid public key input`  (PublikKey expects a  `PublicKeyInitData: number | string | Buffer | Uint8Array | number[] | PublicKeyData`)

That is why I had to out it into a try-catch block.

Is there any other (better) way to achieve this? It looks ugly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To validate a Solana public key may be a wallet address, you should both use `isOnCurve()` and the `PublicKey` constructor like you are doing.

The error thrown makes sense. If the address is not a public key, it should not be able to be instantiated.

Perhaps there could be another function made native to @solana/web3.js that takes care of validating wallet addresses for you in the future.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I wasn't sure I was doing it right

Comment: this returns false for some addresses like "4ig5eTKvBefXB9Pqwq2rCJTGFRNATEa7geNzeuVQGmAE", any idea why?

Comment: yup i tried with a wallet address "Eej78Z5E4w5sSreb8w8esQqTVwBuyT8La2ypa8jiY3Tw". but it returns false. Although this is correct wallet address.

Answer (score 6):

`PublicKey.isOnCurve()` return true only if the address is on `ed25519 curve` such addresses generated from `Keypair` and returns false for off-curve addresses such as derived addresses from `PublicKey.findProgramAddress()` though they can be valid public key.

```
const owner = new PublicKey("DS2tt4BX7YwCw7yrDNwbAdnYrxjeCPeGJbHmZEYC8RTb");
console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBytes())); // true
console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toString())); // true

const ownerPda = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [owner.toBuffer()],
    new PublicKey("worm2ZoG2kUd4vFXhvjh93UUH596ayRfgQ2MgjNMTth"),
)[0];
console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve(ownerPda.toString())); // false

console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve([owner, 18])); // false

const RAY_MINT = new PublicKey("4k3Dyjzvzp8eMZWUXbBCjEvwSkkk59S5iCNLY3QrkX6R");
console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve(new PublicKey(RAY_MINT))); // true

console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve("fasddfasevase")); // throws error
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same (validate a solana wallet address) and works for me.

isOnCurve return true if the public key has a valid format, but I think this is not sufficient for verify a wallet address because I'm tested some public keys from devnet and mainnet-beta and ever return true  (without care about the env) unless I used invalid key.

This is a public key from devnet, you can try with this to test:

```
8B9wLUXGFQQJ6VpzhDMpmHxByAvQBXhwSsZUwjLz971x
```

My code looks like:

```
var connection = new web3.Connection(
   web3.clusterApiUrl('devote'),
   'confirmed',
  );

const publicKey = new web3.PublicKey("8B9wLUXGFQQJ6VpzhDMpmHxByAvQBXhwSsZUwjLz971x");

console.log(await web3.PublicKey.isOnCurve(publicKey))
```

Should print `true`

Comment: Thx Vicente for your comment. In fact, in my code, the address you provide results in true. You can test it on a Replit I set up here: https://replit.com/@cdelalama/VerifyAddress1?v=1#index.js  (fork it and edit it on a workspace).
I've noticed that depending on how I import the web3.js module it behaves differently: `import {PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js'` returns true, but `import PublicKey from '@solana/web3.js' ` or  `import web3 from '@solana/web3.js'` returns false. I'm not an expert javascript developer so I don't know what the difference is, maybe someone can explain

Comment: I also tried yours and set up another replit here: https://replit.com/@cdelalama/VerifyAdress2?v=1#index.js
But I can't understand the first part of your code `var connection = new web3.Connection(
   web3.clusterApiUrl('devote'),
   'confirmed',
  );`

Without it is very similar to mine, and can't make it work with that block

Comment: Same issue, it returns false for a bunch of addresses such as `4ig5eTKvBefXB9Pqwq2rCJTGFRNATEa7geNzeuVQGmAE`

Answer (score 1):

`isOnCurve` expects a `Uint8Array` format for publicKey argument. So you must do `publicKey.toBytes()` to get byte array representation of the publicKey.

```
 const validateSolanaAddress = async (addr: string) => {
      let publicKey: PublicKey;
      try {
          publicKey = new PublicKey(addr);
          return await PublicKey.isOnCurve(publicKey.toBytes());
        } catch (err) {
          return false;
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Connection only to validate wallet address. A minimum working example should be something like this:

```
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'

const address = new PublicKey("8B9wLUXGFQQJ6VpzhDMpmHxByAvQBXhwSsZUwjLz971x");
console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve(address));
```